# In how many ways can this be done if it is permitted that the two committees can overlap?

Tags: combinatorics

From a group of n people, two non-empty committees (call them A and B) are to be formed,
possibly leaving some members of the group on neither committee.

(a) In how many ways can this be done if it is permitted that the two committees can overlap?

My solution:

If committee A has x people and committee B has y people, then we have $ n \choose x $$ n \choose y $ ways

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways of choosing committee A would almost be the total
number of subsets of a n´set, which $2^n$
. However, that would including the
possible of an empty committee. Hence there are $2^n -1 $ possible committees.
Since the choices of committee B is independent of A, there would be the
same number of possible committees B, and therefore ways of $(2^n -1 )^2$ 
choosing the two committees.

Comment: Yes, also observe that $\sum_{x=1}^{n}{n\choose x}=2^n-1$, so your previous approach still holds.

Comment: which is Also $(2^{n+1}-1)(2^{n-1}-1)+2^{n-1}$ for a random fact.

Comment: Your solution is correct.